# Google Cloud Functions, createCustomToken returning null in the Client?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions

I'm new to building chrome extensions and trying to use the Firebase authentication from my webapp in my chrome extension

What I want to happen: (please let me know if this isn't the right way to do it)

1. User logins/signs up in webapp
2. Upon sign up, call my function to `createCustomToken` and return the token to the client
3. Save the token into chrome storage so that my extension can authenticate the user.

The problem:

When I call the function all I get back in the console is `{data: null}` and not the customToken.

Firestore Function Code

```
const {logger} = require("firebase-functions");
const {onRequest} = require("firebase-functions/v2/https");
const {onCall, HttpsError} = require("firebase-functions/v2/https");
const {initializeApp} = require("firebase-admin/app");
const {getAuth} = require("firebase-admin/auth");
const {getFirestore} = require("firebase-admin/firestore");


initializeApp();


exports.createToken = onCall((request) => {

  const uid = request.auth.uid;

  getAuth().createCustomToken(uid).then((customToken) => {
    return customToken
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    return error;
  });
  
});
```

Webapp Code (Next.js)

```
// the code below is currently running onClick

const addMessage = () => {
  const createToken = httpsCallable(functions, 'createToken');
  createToken().then(result => {
    console.log(result); >> the result in console is "data: null"
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function isn't returning anything to the caller.  You need a return statement at the top level to return the result of the async call chain.

```
  return getAuth().createCustomToken(uid).then((customToken) => {
    return customToken
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    return error;
  });
```

Comment: Legend thank you! can't believe I missed that